# Revert Azure Devops Repo to unmerged state if Pipeline Unit Tests fail

Tags: json, azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have an Azure Pipeline that merges into a repository that converts .json files representing customer orders into C# objects. Naturally, if the design or naming of these C# objects ever changes, the old orders will become unusable, so we run a script 'Migrating' all these outdated .jsons to conform to the new model.

Our current pipeline that merges dev into production Migrates our .jsons, and we run a PowerShell unit test script after the pipeline's completion to ensure that the .jsons have successfully Migrated. We'd like to place this test into the pipeline itself, but there are two conditions we'd prefer to meet.

1. If the Test fails, not only abort the merge, but revert the .jsons to their un-Migrated versions.
2. Give us the option to continue the merge anyway, in the event that the website encounters an error so critical and urgent we are willing to bear the loss of a few quotes.

Are these conditions feasible?

Comment: Hi there, have you got a chance to check the suggestion below?

Comment: Thank you for asking, and sorry for my slow response. We've come to a solution. Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you may consider using [Build validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#build-validation) as the [Branch policies and settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#build-validation).

Basically, let's assume your production code is in the `Production` branch; then you can create a `Dev` branch and push your new commits into the `Dev` branch. When setting the Build validation policy on the `Production` branch, the PR request will not be completed if the build fails, which contains the unit test. Therefore the new code from `Dev`  branch will not be merged into the `Production` branch.

In the meanwhile, other branch policies may also help you with the code version control. Hope the following documents can help as well.

[Require a minimum number of reviewers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#require-a-minimum-number-of-reviewers)

[Check for linked work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#check-for-linked-work-items)

[Check for comment resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#check-for-comment-resolution)

[Limit merge types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#limit-merge-types)